# Loading another view in the same viewController clears non UI properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController controlling several different views in Xcode. I want to set a label on the incoming view using information from the current view. I know labels and other UI elements get reset when the view is loaded, but my non UI `@property` is being set to nil as well.

Here is my property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* username;
```

Here is the code that sets it:

```
//NSLog(@"%@",dict);
if ([dict[@"login"] intValue]){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"JoinSuccess" sender:sender];
    self.username = dict[@"user"];
```

Here is the code that tries to use it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"%@", self.username);
self.welcomeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome, %@",self.username];
}
```

I've tried setting `username` both before and after `performSegueWithIdentifier`, but in either case when I try to reference it in `viewDidLoad` the value is nil. Any idea as to why it's reseting my `@property`? My guess is maybe it's creating a new instance of my viewController. If that's the case, how can I pass the needed variable?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called when the first time a UIViewController's view property is accessed.

Comment: assign username to another string in viewDidload it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said the viewController will be created again when ever you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`. You could set the value in the new instance. You can do this in

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
   vc.username = dict[@"user"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! `dict` is a local variable, is there any way to set it from within the method?

Comment: If you are using `performSegue` for transition there is no other way, you should set this in `prepareForSegue ` only make `dict` as a property to get it there. Otherwise instead of using segue, use `instanstiateViewControllerWith..` then do push/present from there

Comment: This worked for me:
    `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    LoginViewController *new = [segue destinationViewController];
    new.username = self.username;
}`
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you have to add another method to pass value from one view controller to another view controller .

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
   nextViewcontroller *nextViewcontrollerObjt = [segue
destinationViewController]; 
// apply setter to set value of next view
    nextViewcontrollerobject.title = nextViewControllerTitleString;
    nextViewcontrollerobject.variable_1= currentView_variable1; 
    nextViewcontrollerobject.variable_2 =currentView_variable2;
         }
```